# Problems moving animation to iOS4 blocks

Tags: iphone, animation, ios4

I have a working view animation, that curls up a container view, while the containerview.subviews changes. (before the animation a UITableView will be shown, after it is a custom view, name keypadView)

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:.75];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp 
                       forView:containerView 
                         cache:YES];
[secondView removeFromSuperview];
[containerView addSubview:keypadView];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Now I want to rewrite this code for the iOS4 block-based api, as I want to use the completion block. I wrote this:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:containerView
                  duration:.75 
                   options:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp
                animations:^{
                    NSLog(@"Hey Ho");
                    [secondView removeFromSuperview];
                    [containerView addSubview:keypadView];
                } 
                completion:NULL];
```

The views switch — but not animated.

**what is wrong with my code?**

**Edit**

```
completion: ^(BOOL completed){
    NSLog(@"completed %d", completed);
}
```

doesn't help, as NULL is an accepted value, according to the docs

Comment: I've edited my answer to show the correct block animation option you should use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do:
options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp
instead of:
options:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp

That is why your code works now :).

Comment: yeah, this was the problem. I found it weeks ago but I forgot to write an answer.

Comment: If I could vote this up more than once I would - so easy to miss that, just lost about 1/2 an hour :)

Answer (score 2):

The sample in the UIView class reference *may* be wrong - or maybe there's a bug with adding and removing views in the `animations` block object, but the only way I've been able to get it to work is as follows:

```
[secondView removeFromSuperview];
[containerView addSubview:keypadView];
[UIView transitionWithView:containerView
                  duration:.75
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp
                animations:^{}
                completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                    NSLog(@"finished %d", finished);
                }];
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but this code doesnt work for me neither.

Comment: Woops! The block animation options should use `UIViewAnimationOption` instead of `UIViewAnimationTransition`. So the correct animation option is `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp`. Edited my answer to fix that. Sorry :)

Comment: And in fact further testing proves that the view manipulation (removeFromSuperview & addSubview) work just fine within the animation block object. It appears that there was a PBKAC, not in Apple's documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Did you leave `[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];` above your new block?

Answer (score 1):

Is the completion block always `NULL`? Try putting an `NSLog` statement in there or something. I don't know if `NULL` blocks would mess it up.